# AfxMessageBox going on background

Tags: c++, mfc

In a connection check i am showing a modal dialog to ensure the connection. But to give people escape from the modal dialog i want to a message box to keep try connection or exit the application.

### Source Code :

```
void CRoboVibMainFrame::OpenSystemSettingsDialog(int activeTabIndex /*= 0*/)
{

while (activeTabIndex >= 0)
{
    m_settingsDialog = std::make_unique<SettingsDialog>(this,activeTabIndex);
    m_settingsDialog->DoModal();
    activeTabIndex = GetNotConnectedPSVControl();
    if (AfxMessageBox(Polytec::Text::ToMessageString(IDS_PSV_SYSTEM_EXIT_WINDOW_MSG), MB_YESNO) == IDNO)
    {
        ::ExitProcess(0);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

But the Messagebox is alway showing in the background. I want it on front. What is wrong in my code? Please suggest.

Comment: Try using `MessageBox` and passing in the HWND of the modal dialog.

Comment: How will i pass hwnd to the messagebox?

Comment: AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd();

Comment: @ Tom Tom i am not getting your point. Should i use MessageBox instead or AfxMessageBox? If so then how will i pass the hwnd?Not getting it. :(

Comment: `DoModal` returns when the modal dialog box is done (closed), not when it is opened). So your AfxMessageBox will display after that and not give the user a chance to exit from that `DoModal`.

Comment: @ Werner Henze : do you mean it's not possible to give people any chance but only force to satisfy the condition?? There is no way to exit the application from another afxmessagebox over the modal dialog?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at using multi threading.

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju: I meant:  ::MessageBox( AfxGetMainWnd() ->GetSafeHwnd(), _T("What is going wrong?"), _T("Question"), MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION );  But I don't know if this solve your problem. If not, create your own CDialog and SetWindoPos(..) in OnInitDialog().

Comment: @ Tom Tom : Please see me below answer. Using this fix i was able to get what i need :
CWnd::PostMessage(WM_SYSKEYDOWN);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bring the AfxMessageBox to front by this fix :

CWnd::PostMessage(WM_SYSKEYDOWN);

I am not sure if this is the only way. But it fixed my issues. This can help someone.

Comment: Interesting, That's like press Alt-Key. Microsoft should fix that. [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788540/mfc-cdialog-domodal-cant-show-window-if-parent-window-message-queue-is-busy)